# Error when compiling cradle.c

Tags: c, gcc, gcc-warning

```
#include "cradle.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
char tmp[MAX_BUF];
char Look;

int  Getchar()
{
    Look = Getchar();
    return Getchar;
}


void Error(char *s)
{
    printf("\nError: %s.",s);
}

void Abort(char *s)
{
    Error(s);
    exit(1);
}

void Expected(char *s)
{
    sprintf(tmp,"%s Expected",s);
    Abort(tmp);
}

void Match(char x)
{
    if(Look==x) {
        Getchar();
    } else {
        sprintf(tmp,"'%c'",x);
        Expected(tmp);
    }
}

char GetName()
{
    char c = Look;
    if(!isalpha(Look)) {
        sprintf(tmp,"Name");
        Expected(tmp);
    }

    Getchar();
    return toupper(c);
}

char GetNum()
{
    char c = Look;
    if(!isdigit(Look)) {
        sprintf(tmp,"Integer");
        Expected(tmp);
    }
    GetChar();

    return c;
}

void Emit(char *s)
{
    printf("\t%s", s);
}

void EmitLn(char *s)
{
    Emit(s);
    printf("\n");
}

void Init()
{
    Getchar();
}
```

It is for a compiler that I'm trying to build myself, also tried to take off void of it, but it's not working:

> Cradle.c: In function ‘Getchar’: cradle.c:10:8: warning: return makes
>   integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]  return
>   Getchar;
>           ^ /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o: na
>   função `_start': (.text+0x20): referência indefinida para`main'
>   /tmp/ccavx14D.o: na função `GetNum': cradle.c:(.text+0x1a9):
>   referência indefinida para`GetChar' collect2: error: ld returned 1
>   exit status

Comment: Your return in `GetChar()` is returning the function not the character. I am assuming you wanted to return `Look` in which case you should probably change the return type to `char` to match what you are returning.

Comment: Thx, I'll try it

Comment: Secondarily - it seems like you have an infinite recursion call in the `Getchar` function since it is calling into itself and there is no base case. I am guessing that you meant for it to call some other function that is retrieving a character from somewhere.

Comment: what is the contents of the local header file: `cradle.h`?

Comment: this statement: `Look = Getchar();` should be: `Look = getchar();`.  This is a very good example of why the standard C library functions (with only a capitalization or other trivial change) should not be declared in user code.

Comment: error messages should be output to `stderr`, not `stdout` so the `Error()` function is doing the wrong thing. Suggest: `fprintf( stderr, "\nError: %s\n.",s);`